# Annualizing the Sharpe Ratio

Tags: finance, sharpe-ratio

I am doing some calculations and I am working currently with the weekly Sharpe Ratio. Can I annualize the Sharpe ratio by multiplying with the square root of 52?

Greetings!

Comment: Yes, assuming that the time series does not have significant positive or negative autocorrelation.

Comment: thank you for your help!